# is there way to install ros on DexterOS or Raspbian for Robots?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, i think the question is clear from the topic
now i have gopigo robot and i was trying to install ros on it, so i can start using SLAM, so is there way to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278991/is-there-way-to-install-ros-on-dexteros-or-raspbian-for-robots-??/) by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2018-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's [ROSberryPi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi) for Raspbian.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2